# HTML5 video not working in Firefox

Tags: html, video

The following video element is not working in Firefox but seems to work fine in Chrome. Can anyone suggest why this is?

```
<video width="150" height="55" autoplay loop>
    <source src="logo-video2.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
    <source src="logo-video2.ogg" type="video/ogv" />
    <source src="logo-video2.webm" type="video/webm" />
    <img src="logo.jpg" alt="dasd">
</video>
```

Answer (score 4):

Try adding this to your .htaccess file.

```
AddType video/ogg   .ogv
AddType video/mp4   .mp4
AddType video/webm  .webm
```

Answer (score 1):

Try moving the OGG or WebM source to the top of the stack (i.e. making it the first one).

Which version of Firefox is it not working in?

With modern browsers you only need to provide WebM and MP4 sources, unless you're specifically targetting older versions of Firefox (below version 4 I think).

Answer (score 1):

When I reconverted my video using Miro Video Converter it starts working. Previously I was using AVS Converter. It seems to me that some converters or Firefox doesn't follow or fully implement VP8 standard.

But everything was working perfectly in Chrome (+1 for Chrome) regardless converter used.